# When to use "verb to be"/"do" in question?

Tags: grammar

When I ask questions like "Are you tried?", "Is he usually come on time?", is it grammatically correct or not?

Can I ask "Do you tried?" and "Does he usually come on time?" What rules apply when I ask questions like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a sentence has an auxiliary verb, the corresponding yes-or-no question uses the same auxiliary verb.

> *You are trying.*  → *Are you trying?*
>
> *We have ordered lunch.* → *Have we ordered lunch?*
>
> *He can dance.*  →  *Can he dance?*
>
> *We should call home.* → *Should we call home?*
>
> *He was knocked down.* → *Was he knocked down?*

If a sentence has no auxiliary verb, the yes-or-no question uses *do* (not *be* or any other auxiliary):

> *He tried.* → *He did try.* → *Did he try?*
>
> *He usually comes on time.* → *He does usually come on time.* → *Does he usually come on time?*

You need to know one more rule.

In sentences like *He did try* with an auxiliary verb followed by an ordinary verb, it is the auxiliary verb that inflects for tense and subject-verb agreement. So you say *did try*, not *do tried* or *are tried*. The other verb (*try*) is not inflected, except for the progressive, passive, and perfect.

Comment: +1 you might add in something on the usage of had/have in questions for a more thorough answer.

Comment: So, as Jason didn't explicitly say, neither "Are you tried" nor "Do you tried" is grammatical in the sense you mean.

Comment: I added an example with *have*.